# Asian movie with someone who can destroy bones with a look and an immortal character killed by poison

Tags: story-identification, movie

Looking for an Asian movie that has various characters possessing various superpowers.

One of the main female heroines has the power to look into anyone’s eyes and destroy their bones. The first time she does this, the movie has graphic animations.

There is another character who is immortal but in his death scene, he kisses a woman who possesses poisonous abilities which eventually kill the bugs who keep him alive.

Another character manipulates his hair as his super ability.

Answer (score 4):

*Shinobi: Heart Under Blade* (2005)?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shinobi:_Heart_Under_Blade):

> - Tomoka Kurotani as Kagero - poison specialist. Poison flows within her veins and she is able to breathe poison at enemies or poisoning them with a kiss. [...]
> - Yukie Nakama as Oboro - the Iga leader who has the "eyes of destruction", completely incapacitating an opponent with one glance.
> - Kippei Shiina as Yakushiji Tenzen - he is the host to parasitic worms which prevent him from aging and heal any wounds he sustained, allowing him to quickly recover from nearly any injury.

---

Found with the Google query `asian movie powers immortal bugs site:imdb.com/title`.

Comment: Thank you so much!